# Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've been playing with the [`fabcar` sample](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html).

I got an error when enrolling the admin.

> Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: read ECONNRESET
>    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27

Before this I was playing around with building your first network. I managed to execute it well.
So when I transitioned to *Writing Your First Application*, I brought down the existing network:

```sh
$ ./byfn.sh down
$ docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep fabcar | awk '{print $3}')
```

I checked running dockers after starting fabric

```sh
$ ./startFabric.sh javascript
$ docker ps
```

Out:

```
f24bd3c10a75        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0-a139c9f32bcd86b26c02c1cfecba01c235a9007e24c34b03cb1d82d000696338   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                                                    dev-peer1.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0
8fc39b671604        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0-264b0a1cb5efbecaac5cf8990339c24474dc8435c6e10f10f2be565d555d0e94   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                                                    dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar-1.0
a9412c3eed57        dev-peer1.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0-791f4e9c59e5c5ae44b5e63c754aaf47cfa4757490019879665238e39ab45594   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                                                    dev-peer1.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0
4d96477f2245        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0-5c906e402ed29f20260ae42283216aa75549c571e2e380f3615826365d8269ba   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0
da77e8a95820        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest                                                                          "/bin/bash"              16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                                                    cli
6ec21ecb773b        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp                       peer0.org1.example.com
ecfe4b450657        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp                       peer0.org2.example.com
6838f9c4151d        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp                     peer1.org2.example.com
b5cbf943217a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp                       peer1.org1.example.com
a6b50a64328f        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8984->5984/tcp   couchdb3
43b06333763e        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp   couchdb2
b06b9d7b5e7c        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp   couchdb1
ff52abcf0dd9        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb0
689f1c4417ae        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest                                                                        "orderer"                17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                       orderer.example.com
```

There's no `ca.example.com`.

```sh
$ docker logs -f ca.example.com
```

> Error: No such container: ca.example.com

Any thoughts about the error?

Answer (score 0):

*Writing Your First Application* does not create Fabric CA, as you can see from the [byfn.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/byfn.sh) script.

You can take a look at the ca.example.com from [basic-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/basic-network/docker-compose.yml) (another fabric-sample), and add it in your *write your first application* (maybe need a little bit modification in container volumn, depends on where is your crypto-config).

Hope this helps.